# Word or phrase for when a car goes over a pothole

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When on the road a car goes over a pothole (bump on the road), what do you call it in English?

Comment: Most of the expressions people use do not belong on a public site such as this!

Comment: "Hit a pothole"

Comment: @Jay A. Little A 'bump' in the road is usually regarded as a raised area that is higher than the surrounding road area. A pothole, almost by definition, is a hollow or hole in the road that is lower than the surrounding road area. However, a car wheel passing over either one of these can cause the sensation and sound of a 'bump' within the car.

Comment: As James indicates, a *bump on the road* is a raised area, just like a bump on your forehead. https://www.google.com/search?q=bump+on+your+forehead+image&num=20&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=1kthhflcEGpf-M%253A%252CaHk4UdDxzaZMfM%252C_&usg=AFrqEzcQ9y3HBI43IUuQeC1In_Lqx-DS-g&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS-d2s_57dAhUqTd8KHQu7By4Q9QEwC3oECAIQGg#imgrc=1kthhflcEGpf-M:

Comment: Honestly, I was going to ask OP whether he meant a 'pothole' or a 'bump' because yes they are opposites (concave vs convex). But then I realized it doesn't matter. The phrase is the same "hit a bump" and "hit a pothole". Just don't ask me why! XD

Comment: Yes. I agree about **hit**. That was for OP's benefit. You can **hit a roadblock** too, but I don't think it means you collide with it. You *encounter* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When on the road a car goes over a pothole (bump on the road), what do you call it in English?

We call the hole a "pothole", and we call the resulting action of driving over it a "bump"!

Perhaps you are looking for some other way of describing it? Or some adjectives to describe the feeling, or the sound? Maybe these will help:

> My car hit a pothole and I felt the bump.
>
> I felt a thump as my wheels hit the pothole.
>
> As I struck the pothole I heard and felt the bump as my car's suspension took the stress.